# program instantly terminates instead of staying in a constant loop

Tags: java

i am trying to make a program that, when a button is pressed it will start to create many invisible frames to the point it should crash a pc. however when i try and run it the console instantly terminates

this is the code for the program:

```
 public class JavaTester extends JFrame {
   static JFrame frame;
static ImageIcon img;
private static boolean a = false;

public JavaTester() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(670, 700);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0,255,0,0));
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            a = true;

        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {

        if (a) {
            while (true)
                new JavaTester();

        }
    } while (a = false);
  }
}
```

is this a problem with the way my loops are ordered or is there something else that makes it instantly stop running?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:
   `while (a = false)`;

By doing that, `a` is set to `false`.

Instead you need to use [conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) **equal to** `(a == false)`

Comment: In fact you shouldn't compare booleans to true or false as it leads to exactly this issue, just do `while (!a)`

Comment: yup that keeps it running, iv'e always been bad with small things like that thank you :)